# How to handle a window which automatically closes and says window not found error

Tags: java, selenium

How to handle a window which automatically closes and says window not found error

Please find code below :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'New Incident')]")).click();
Sleepforsec(10000);

Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it=allWindowHandles.iterator();
String parent=it.next();
String child=it.next();  
System.out.println(parent +" ... "+child);
driver.switchTo().window(child);
Sleepforsec(8000);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='arid_WIN_0_303530000']")).sendKeys("Bolton");


driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('reg_img_304248190')")).click(); //for clicking search button
Sleepforsec(10000);
Set<String> allWindowHandles1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it1=allWindowHandles1.iterator();
String parent1=it1.next();
String child1=it1.next();
String child2=it1.next();//search
System.out.println(parent1 +" ... "+child2);
driver.switchTo().window(child2);    

Sleepforsec(6000);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Brent']"));  
//use DoubleClick method to double click on any element
builder.doubleClick(e1).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.className("btntextdiv")).click();// this is where window closes automatically. Then It shud switch back to previous window.

driver.switchTo().window(Child);
```

Comment: I don't know what Sleepforsec is , but you should use Sleeper.sleepTight instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could create a JavascriptExecutor that changes/alters the embedded function that is closing the window, and then the behavior of the window could be altered that way dynamically.